# Gradle compile error "Duplicate files"

Tags: android, gradle

I have added library "TimeSquare" for android,from 
https://github.com/square/android-times-square
I use AndroidStudio. I have decared in dependencies  and have made ./gradlew clean

```
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.0.2'
```

But when i run app i have compile error

```
: duplicate files during packaging of APK /home/alexgarmash/android-mobile-banking/MobileBanking/build/apk/MobileBanking-debug-unaligned.apk
```

Execution failed for task ':MobileBanking:packageDebug'.

> Duplicate files copied in APK AndroidManifest.xml
>       File 1: /home/alexgarmash/android-mobile-banking/MobileBanking/build/libs/MobileBanking-debug.ap_
>       File 2: /home/alexgarmash/android-mobile-banking/MobileBanking/build/libs/MobileBanking-debug.ap_

This is Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
<artifactId>android-times-square</artifactId>
<version>(insert latest version)</version>
<type>apklib</type>
```